# Singleton instance using a Mutex

Tags: singleton, mutex

I want to have a singleton class that can be shared across processes. So I naturally used the Mutex in .NET 4.0.

Now I have two instances of the same application running. One modifies the "Name" property of this Singleton and all I want is the other application to pick up this change. But even after the first instance releases the Mutex, the second instance is not able to succeed in the WaitOne call. I wonder why and what I am doing wrong in the code below? Please note that the entry point is the method RunSingletonAcrossProcesses().

### Here's my Singleton Class

```
public class SingletonAcrossProcesses
{
    
private static SingletonAcrossProcesses _instance;
    
private static Mutex _mutex = new Mutex(true, @"Global\" + "sivablogz.wordpress.com SingletonMutexDemo");

    protected SingletonAcrossProcesses()
    {
    }

    public static SingletonAcrossProcesses GetInstance()
    {
        if (_mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new SingletonAcrossProcesses();
            }
            _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }            
        
        return _instance;                            
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static void RunSingletonAcrossProcesses()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Instantiate the singleton...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        SingletonAcrossProcesses instance = SingletonAcrossProcesses.GetInstance();

        if (instance != null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(instance.Name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a name for the instance...");
                instance.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The Instance name is: " + instance.Name);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The Singleton Instance could not be obtained.");            
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Siva

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be running into this:

> If name is not null and initiallyOwned is true, the calling thread owns the mutex only if the named system mutex was created as a result of this call. Since there is no mechanism for determining whether the named system mutex was created, it is better to specify false for initiallyOwned when calling this constructor overload. You can use the Mutex(Boolean, String, Boolean) constructor if you need to determine initial ownership.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf.aspx

Comment: I can clearly see that initiallyOwned is true for the first process's main thread that gets hold of the mutex but it looks like even after I call ReleaseMutex or CloseMutex, another process's thread is not able to get hold of the Mutex with WaitOne. Not sure why.

Comment: The mutex still exists even after you close or release it, I believe you would have to dispose of it (it inherites WaitHandle, which implements IDisposable) to make it go away.